# Top selling product by category - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am looking to write a query to pull the top selling product per category from a schema. The schema on a simplified view looks like this:

| Category | Orderid | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 12as | 234 |
| Sport | 421bb | 3434 |
| Steel | 35366cd | 12355 |
| Food | 3421ww | 362 |
| Sport | 546421qw | 436456 |

etc etc.

I am using amazon redshift. I want to find the distinct category, its top selling order ID and the sum of the revenue.

`Select distinct category, orderid, sum(revenue) as rev from XXX`

I've got the start of the query but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function, using `PARTITION BY` with your grouping column then get the top-selling values.

```
SELECT Category,Orderid,Revenue
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Revenue desc) rn
    FROM XXX
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works for you - using Window Function to find the OrderId with the highest revenue, then aggregating:

```
select Category, Sum(Revenue) TotalRevenue, Max(TopSelling) TopSelling
from (
    select *, 
      First_Value(OrderId) over(partition by category order by Revenue desc) TopSelling
    from t
)t
group by Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what your result should look like then you can use Postgres's `DISTINCT ON` expression. This is not to be confused with `DISTINCT`. It "groups" by the specified columns and returns the first row. You can control which first row it returns by using `ORDER BY`.

```sql
create temporary table orders (
  category varchar,
  order_id varchar,
  revenue int 
);

insert into orders (category, order_id, revenue) values
('Food',  '12as',      '234'), 
('Sport', '421bb',     '3434'),
('Steel', '35366cd',   '12355'),
('Food',  '3421ww',    '362'),
('Sport', '546421qw',  '436456');

select distinct on (category) 
       category,
       order_id,
       revenue
from orders
order by category, revenue DESC;

/*
 category | order_id | revenue
----------+----------+---------
 Food     | 3421ww   |     362
 Sport    | 546421qw |  436456
 Steel    | 35366cd  |   12355
*/
```